# What is std::vector::_emplace_back_slow_path / std::vector::_push_back_slow_path?

Tags: c++, stdvector, libc++

When using a call profiler, I noticed a high runtime cost and a high number of allocations in `std::vector::_emplace_back_slow_path`. Because I am concerned about performance, I want this to say "fast path". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to avoid memory reallocation.    If possible, use `reserve()` to set the capacity (if you can reasonably anticipate a reasonable upper bound on what size the vector will grow to) rather than simply adding elements.    Of course, as a general rule, you should also avoid resizing vectors too much within performance critical code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looking at the implementation](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/vector#L1688), the "slow path" is the path taken if a reallocation is needed:

```
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::emplace_back(_Args&&... __args)
{
    if (this->__end_ < this->__end_cap())
    {
        // This is the code that you could call the "fast path"
    }
    else
        __emplace_back_slow_path(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
}
```

This also applies to `std::vector::_push_back_slow_path`.

Comment: You could try calling `std::vector::reserve` if you know in advance approximately how large the vector needs to be.